# ReactDOM.render Cannot read property

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-dom

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import buttonsInstance from 'components/button-instance';
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and `button-instance.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

const buttonsInstance = (
  <div>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Large button</Button>
      <Button bsSize="large">Large button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary">Default button</Button>
      <Button>Default button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small">Small button</Button>
      <Button bsSize="small">Small button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="xsmall">Extra small button</Button>
      <Button bsSize="xsmall">Extra small button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
  </div>
);
```

I'm trying to use `reactbootstrap` from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html .

Then I got error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 571b93c…:657)
    at fn (bootstrap 571b93c…:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (log-apply-result.js:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 571b93c…:657)
    at module.exports (bootstrap 571b93c…:706)
    at bootstrap 571b93c…:706
```

I'm use `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server` and `es6`. My `react` and `react-dom` is up to date. I have no idea about how to fix this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Import the `ReactDOM` like this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Its a default import (import the complete package to use the different methods of that) not named import, that's why you are getting the error:

> Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Or you can directly import the `render` method from `react-dom` like this:

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
```

now use `render` to directly render the component:

```
render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: is ReactDOM a default export in react-dom ?

Comment: yes, import the complete package then use the render method of that :)

Comment: But the statement `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` is giving error saying `[ts] Module ''react-dom'' has no default export.
` of version `15.0.1`

Comment: @JSantosh you need to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to your tsconfig.json file

Comment: my mistake was a missing semi colon but ... since when does a js file require that ? Is it because of the runtime minification of the file?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 can you share the error message? are you using typescript?

Comment: I've moved on from that error now :-( No trace of that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `react` version and `react-dom` versions are compatible.

Ex. For `react` version `16.9.0`, use 'react-dom' version `16.9.0`

Answer (score 1):

If you get the following error

```
Cannot read property xxx of undefined
```

And if you're using `react-script-ts` as well as `rollup` use `import * as ...`

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you so much :)
But one question, why the notation changes? I'm curious whether or not it depends on the fact that you use react-script-ts because I don't use it. And I don't understand it logically, like if the author of each React and ReactDOM has made it exported as default, they it should stay being exported as default in my reasoning, why it changes?